# How to get slanted borders in CSS

Tags: html, css

So I've seen [this website](http://html5up.net/uploads/demos/solid-state/).

This website has [this cool effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvpOO.png) on every `section` end.

How to make this effect in css? I've tried a few things, but nothing works. Please please help! It's looks great.

Comment: Are you looking for the slanted area or the wave like pattern in the top? If it is the former then you could use gradients or pseudo-elements + transform.

Comment: @Harry Yes, the slanted area.

Comment: When posting to SO, if you've "tried a few things", it would help us to see your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is so much you can learn from just inspecting using the developers tools from Firefox or Chrome...

and this is just what I took from that website:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjoWYe

the important code is this

html

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

css

```
.wrapper::before, .wrapper::after {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
content: "";
display: block;
height: 6.5em;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;}

.wrapper::before, .wrapper::after {
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cpolygon points='0,100 100,0 100,100' style='fill:%232e3141;' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this! I have one question though, where is the image for?

Comment: it is an **SVG**. I highly recomend you to read about it, there is so much you can do with it!  This is the first thing that pop ups from google if you search for SVG: "Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) is an XML-based vector image format for two-dimensional graphics."

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was really helpful.

Comment: @GCyrillus you're not supposed to insert content inside that element. You want to use it next to another to make it look like a border...

Comment: @Granola okay, thought you where looking for something of that kind : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwyZod (gradient instead svg for the demo ;) )